# Writing a List of Dictionaries to seperate JSONs

Tags: python, json

I do have dictionary, with each value as a list.

I want to write individual items to separate JSON files.
For example

```py
data_to_write = {"Names":["name1", "name2", "name3"], "email":["mail1", "mail2", "mail3"]}
```

Now I want 3 jsons i.e `data1.jsob, data2.json, data3.json` in the following(approx) format.

data1.json

```json
{
    Name: name1,
    email: mail1
}
```

data2.json

```
{
    Name: name2,
    email: mail2
}
```

and so on.

My current approach is

```py
    for file_no in range(no_of_files):
        for count, (key, info_list) in enumerate(data_to_write.items()):
            for info in info_list:
                with open(
                     os.path.join(self.path_to_output_dir, str(file_no)) + ".json",
                     "a",
                ) as resume:
                    json.dump({key: info}, resume)
```

But this is wrong. Any helps appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, `"But this is wrong"` is not a description of the symptoms. What is actually happening and why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: @quamrana it writes the same data in every file. And not in the required format but writes the separate dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use pandas to do the work for you. Read the dictionary into a dataframe, then iterate the rows of the dataframe to produce the json for each row:

```py
import pandas as pd

data_to_write = {"Names":["name1", "name2", "name3"], "email":["mail1", "mail2", "mail3"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_to_write).rename(columns={'Names':'Name'})
for i in range(len(df)):
    jstr = df.iloc[i].to_json()
    with open(f"data{i+1}.json", "w") as f:
        f.write(jstr)
```

Output (each line is in a separate file):

```
{"Name":"name1","email":"mail1"}
{"Name":"name2","email":"mail2"}
{"Name":"name3","email":"mail3"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
import json

data_to_write = {
    "Names": ["name1", "name2", "name3"],
    "email": ["mail1", "mail2", "mail3"],
}

for i, val in enumerate(zip(*data_to_write.values()), 1):
    d = dict(zip(data_to_write, val))
    with open(f"data{i}.json", "w") as f_out:
        json.dump(d, f_out, indent=4)
```

This writes `data(1..3).json` with content:

```json
# data1.json
{
    "Names": "name1",
    "email": "mail1"
}

# data2.json
{
    "Names": "name2",
    "email": "mail2"
}

...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import json

data_to_write = {
    "Names": ["name1", "name2", "name3"],
    "email": ["mail1", "mail2", "mail3"],
}

for ind, val in enumerate(zip(*data_to_write.values())):
    jsn = dict(zip(data_to_write, val))
    print(jsn)

    with open("data{}.json".format(ind), "w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(jsn))
```